# How to remove suffix from name on the frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, magento-1, customer-account, customer-attribute

I am making a Magento webshop for company that has a tourboat. I wanted an option when the customer registers an account, where they can select if they have already been on a trip with this boat.

First, I wanted to make a module for this extra Customer Attribute, and create a checkbox on the registration page, but I didn't know how to do it, and the tutorials didn't help me either.

This is why I decided to use the suffix dropdown for this. Normally the suffix dropdown would contain suffixes like: Jr., Sr., etc.

Now, I want to change the default suffix dropdown to the two choices:

- Yes, I have already been on a trip
- No, this is my first trip

But, when I select the above, my name on the account page changes to (for example):

**John Doe Yes, I have already been on a trip**

or

**John Doe No, this is my first trip**

---

How do I remove this suffix from the frontend?
(Or, how do I add a 'yes / no' option as a custom customer attribute to the registration form)

Comment: its hard to say with your question please provide code of your frontend template file for this

Answer (score 1):

Please goto

1. `admin panel-->system-->configuration-->customers-->customer configuration--> Name and Address Options--> here you check " show suffix and suffix dropdown options"`
2. `admin panel-->system-->configuration-->General-->design-->HTML head-->check options here`

Comment: Could you read my question again? :p I only want to remove the suffix from the frontend, not the backend